Accessing new files in a shared volume in Docker
I have 4 Docker containers for my web app:

frontend (React)
backend (Express)
db (Postgres)
OMR (Python)

Frontend, backend and db are running all the time, but OMR is only ran when it is called. There is a shared volume between all the containers, containing the contents of the OMR.
On the frontend, the user uploads a pdf file to be checked. It is then saved to an inputs folder inside the shared volume. The OMR is then called, scans the file and exports it to the outputs folder.
When I upload the file, it shows up successfully inside the shared volume when I access it from the frontend and backend containers. However, when I start the OMR, the files don't show up. I suspect this is because the OMR container copies the files from the host (which does not have the pdf to be scanned) and not the shared volume (which does).
Below is my docker-compose.yaml file:
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        # - PORT=5001
      context: backend
      target: development
    command: npm run start-watch
    environment:
      - DATABASE_DB=root
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - JWT_SECRET=secret
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      # - PORT=5001
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 9229:9229
      - 9230:9230
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/code/src:ro
      - ./backend/package.json:/code/package.json
      - ./backend/package-lock.json:/code/package-lock.json
      - back-notused:/opt/app/node_modules
      - omr-volume:/code/omr
    networks:
      - public
      - private
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db-postgres
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./db/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - public
      - private

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
      target: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/code/src
      - /code/node_modules
      - omr-volume:/app/omr
    networks:
      - public
    depends_on:
      - backend

  omr:
    build:
      context: ./omr 
    environment:
      - OMR_CHECKER_CONTAINER=True
    volumes:
      - ./omr:/app/omr
      - omr-volume:/app
    networks:
      - public
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  public:
  private:

volumes:
  back-notused:
  db-data:
  omr-volume:


What is in the OMR service; how do you invoke it?  Can you give it an HTTP API and make HTTP POST/GET request to it to send it data?  Then you should be able to delete all of the volumes:, except for the db-data storage.

More locally to this question, what directory does the OMR service expect to find its content in?  Will it be upset if the overlapping volume mounts create an empty omr directory in the volume?

The OMR service is written it python. It's invoked using python main.py. You can't make HTTP POST/ requests to but that is the other option I was considering. The OMR expects to find input in app/omr/inputs

The bind mount of the host's ./omr directory means that directory comes from the host and not the named volume.  Do you actually need that bind mount at all?  (You shouldn't usually need to overwrite images' code with bind mounts.)  Does the second mount need to be omr-volume:/app/omr consistent with the other containers?
